# Numpy Toeplitz Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, cublas, numba

I tried constructing a toeplitz matrix in Python using `scipy.linalg.toeplitz(c, r=None)`. Although I was successful, I was not able to maintain the Fortran ordering. I need to make sure that the toeplitz array being constructed maintain a Fortran ordering since I'm calling BLAS functions.

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest to just make a copy in Fortran ordering.  `toeplitz` creates a new array, but doesn't give you control over the ordering.

E.g.

```
x = scipy.linalg.toeplitz([1, 2, 3, 4])
x = np.asfortranarray(x)
```

It is possible to do this in-place, as well, if you want to conserve memory. E.g.

```
x[:] = x.T
x = x.T
```